# Multiple confidence interval by group

Tags: r, group-by, mean, confidence-interval

I am trying to calculate multiple means and 95% ci by group for 90+ columns:

sample data:

```
Group| A_pre  |    A_post |  B_pre |  B_post 

0       20          21        20        23
1       30          10        19        11
2       10          53        30        34
1       22          32        25        20
2       34          40        32        30
0       30          50        NA        40
0       39          40        19        20
1       40          NA        20        20
2       50          10        20        10
0       34          23        30        10
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(gmodels)
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize_all(list(~mean(., trim = 0), ~ci(.,)), na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get the error `Error in UseMethod("ci") :  no applicable method for 'ci' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"`

I can get individual column ci using but that's time consuming for 90 columns:

```
library(rcompanion)
  groupwiseMean(x ~ group,
              data   = df,
              conf   = 0.95,
              digits = 3, na.rm = T)
```

Is there any way around the `gmodels` error or another way forward?

Comment: `summarize_all()` is deprecated, you might try with the replacement `across()`: `summarize(across(everything(), .fns = list(mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE, trim = 0), ci = ~ ci(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))`. It also looks like you are passing `na.rm = TRUE` to `summarize_all()`, perhaps to the `...` argument, but that will not be passed through when you use lambdas with `~` notation, so I've tried to correct that.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas. I am just curious. Why is this not an answer?

Comment: Because it's just a guess. Haven't tested it, don't know what the `gmodels` package is, and most of all the error OP reports getting doesn't make sense to me so I'm skeptical that it actually solves the problem.

Comment: Though, as I typed it, I the error makes sense now. The real issue is their use of `.` rather than `.x` in the lambdas - the `.` with the pipe is the whole data frame. With that putting my mind at ease I'll post an answer.

Comment: Having ran the code ```ciall <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(across(everything(), .fns = list(mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE, trim = 0), ci = ~ ci(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))``` I get this error: ```ℹ In argument: `across(...)`.
ℹ In group 1: `group = 0`.
Caused by warning in `ci.numeric()`:
! No class or unkown class.  Using default calcuation.```.

Comment: @TarJae and now that I've posted as an answer, my suspicions are proved correct and it doesn't work :\  . On the plus side, it encouraged OP to add sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using the `%>%` pipe, `.` refers to the thing being piped in, in this case your data frame. With the `purrr`-style lambdas, you should use `.x` for the argument.

All that said, `summarize_all()` is deprecated. You might try with the replacement `across()`:

```
summarize(across(everything(),
  .fns = list(
    mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE, trim = 0),
    ci = ~ ci(.x, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
))
```

It also looks like you are passing `na.rm = TRUE` to `summarize_all()` to the `...` argument, but that will not be passed through when you use lambdas with `~` notation, so I've tried to correct that.

This is untested with no sample data provided, but I think it should work assume your data columns are all numeric.

Comment: Thank you @ Gregor. I have provided a sample data at the top. Still getting the same error. I think the ```ci``` from ```gmodels``` might be the problem here.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There was an interaction with ```DescTools``` package; without loading ```DescTools``` it works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Will this work:
We could us a own ci function:

```
#custom ci function:

library(dplyr)

ci <- function(x) {
  mean_val <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  se <- sqrt(var(x, na.rm = TRUE) / length(x))
  ci_lower <- mean_val - (1.96 * se)
  ci_upper <- mean_val + (1.96 * se)
  return(c(ci_lower, ci_upper))
}

df %>%
  reframe(across(everything(), list(mean = mean, ci = ci)), .by=Group)
```

```
 Group A_pre_mean  A_pre_ci A_post_mean A_post_ci B_pre_mean B_pre_ci B_post_mean B_post_ci
1     0   30.75000 22.854054    33.50000 19.861911         NA 17.03889    23.25000  11.02616
2     0   30.75000 38.645946    33.50000 47.138089         NA 28.96111    23.25000  35.47384
3     1   30.66667 20.461274          NA  3.396334   21.33333 17.69573    17.00000  11.12000
4     1   30.66667 40.872060          NA 38.603666   21.33333 24.97094    17.00000  22.88000
5     2   31.33333  8.550822    34.33333  9.378052   27.33333 20.05812    24.66667  10.11624
6     2   31.33333 54.115845    34.33333 59.288614   27.33333 34.60855    24.66667  39.21709
```

Comment: Thank you @TarJae for the solution. I experience this error: Warning messages: 1: In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA 2: In sqrt(var(x, na.rm = TRUE)/length(x)) : NaNs produced. I have tried mean_val <- summarise(list(mean = ~ mean, na.rm = TRUE)) which gives error: Error in UseMethod("summarise") :    no applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "formula" Called from: summarise(mean = ~mean, na.rm = TRUE). I am just trying to understand where it's going wrong. –

Comment: get the latest version of dplyr. be sure that your values are numeric. check with `str(df)`

Comment: I updated everything as suggest and now it seems to work fine. Only issue is that I still get ```NA``` as I have a couple of missing values.  You've used ```na.rm = TRUE``` in the function but still returns ```NA```. Any way around this without having to remove the row or imputation?

Answer (score 0):

How you want to approach this might depend on what format of output would be most useful for you, considering that you are looking at groups within 90 columns of data.

At the risk of eliciting horrified gasps, I'm going to propose the cave person approach. But it's easy to understand, and the output may be easier to sort through.

```
Data = read.table(header=TRUE, text="

Group A_pre       A_post   B_pre   B_post 
0       20          21        20        23
1       30          10        19        11
2       10          53        30        34
1       22          32        25        20
2       34          40        32        30
0       30          50        NA        40
0       39          40        19        20
1       40          NA        20        20
2       50          10        20        10
0       34          23        30        10
")

Data$Group = factor(Data$Group)

library(rcompanion)

for(i in 2:5){
  
print(colnames(Data[i]))
  
Data1 = data.frame(Value = Data[,i], Group = Data$Group)
  
GM = groupwiseMean(Value ~ Group, data=Data1,
              conf   = 0.95,
              digits = 3, na.rm = T)

print(GM)

cat("\n")

}
```

.

```
[1] "A_pre"
  Group n Mean Conf.level Trad.lower Trad.upper
1     0 4 30.8       0.95      17.90       43.6
2     1 3 30.7       0.95       8.26       53.1
3     2 3 31.3       0.95     -18.70       81.3

[1] "A_post"
  Group n Mean Conf.level Trad.lower Trad.upper
1     0 4 33.5       0.95       11.4       55.6
2     1 2 21.0       0.95     -119.0      161.0
3     2 3 34.3       0.95      -20.4       89.1

.
.
.
```

Comment: thank you. When I run I only get one output for one variable i.e., "A_pre" I also get the error ```1: In qt(Dist, df = (N - 1)) : NaNs produced```. It otherwise works fine. Just need to get all column outputs as you have above.

Comment: Does the example as I wrote it run as you expect ?

Comment: yes it does. However, the output is still only showing one variable. I can see the full output for all columns in the R console (I can even see it when I run it for my larger dataset), but not in the ```GM``` df. Only output I get is ```Group n Mean Conf.level Trad.lower Trad.upper
      
1 0 35 2.47 0.95 2.30 2.64
2 1 23 2.54 0.95 2.24 2.83
3 2 19 2.26 0.95 2.00 2.52
4 NA 1 2.42 0.95 NaN NaN ```

Comment: I suppose I don't understand.